# Convert tabular data to json from redshift - Select query to fetch the records in json format

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

For example,

Table sample

```
id name
1  abc
2  def
```

I know in sql server there is something called "select * from sample For JSON auto" to fetch the records and output in json format. Is there anything similar kind of thing in redshift ?

sample output:

[{ 'id':'1', 'name':'abc' }, { 'id':'2', 'name':'def' }]

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Comment: Something like this - [{ 
       id:"1",
       name:"abc"
     },
     {
       id:"2",
       name:"def"
     }
    ]

Comment: Hey, not as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: why do you want to do this? Can't you serialise to json in your client e.g. python or java? - if you really need this it could be done with a Redshift UDF, but with some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this? This works by using the postgres cli `psql` to output to csv and then using python's built in csv and json libraries to parse it.

```
pql --csv -c 'select 1 as a, 2 as b union all select 3 as a,4 as b'|python3 -c 'import csv; import sys; import json; s=sys.stdin; d=csv.DictReader(s.readlines()); print(json.dumps(list(d)))'|jq
```

Which outputs this:

```
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  {
    "a": "3",
    "b": "4"
  }
]
```

`pql` here is a zsh alias I use that is nothing more than this:

```
pql () {
    local PSWD=$(cat <password file here>)
    local DSN="redshift DSN ... password=${PSWD} ..."
    psql "${DSN}" "$@"
}
```

Pre-Reqs:

Also you'll need `jq` which can be installed by most package managers and brew if on MacOS.

Python -- the example uses Python 3.

PSQL -- the cli front end to Postgres, installable by most package managers. On Mac for example, using HomeBrew it's `brew install Postgres@12` -- there are a number of versions available.